# How to add header style in json2xls?

Tags: node.js, json2xls

Hi how do I add background color in the header in my xls file using json2xls in nodejs?

```
var xls = json2xls(data, {// should I add it here?});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you able to find solution to this? I also have same requirement .

Comment: Nope :( I just made it simple with no design :D

Comment: @Vinia, Did you find solution for this ?